# IFilters for index service for DICOM c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, indexing, dicom, ifilter

Im trying to use Index service server for searching on DICOM files. I wanted to know if Index service does support .dcm and .dicom file extensions. I did read about IFilters but was unable to find any for DICOM files. Thanks!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what "Index service" you're referring to.  Be specific.  Give details.  Otherwise, nobody can answer your question.  Also, proper DICOM files do not have a .dcm or .dicom file extension.  DICOM files are identified by the DICM preamble that is in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The windows [indexing service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) became ["Windows Search"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) when XP came along.

I've never come across anyone using it for DICOM, but I imagine it wouldn't be too hard to use the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#windows_search_sdk_documentation) to write a filter to pull DICOM tags out of files and index them.

However, I suspect it's just going to result in a massive amount of information overload; a DICOM study typically contains several series plus captures/derived series, and each series could be thousands of individual files (ok the latter less of a problem with modern extended DICOM and one-volume-per-file, but there's still a massive amount of per-slice-files out there and being produced).  File-level indexing alone doesn't sound that useful.  If Windows Search could be made aware of the hierarchy and let you search for studies/series that might be more interesting.  But most people just keep their DICOM in a [PACS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_archiving_and_communication_system) of some sort which will generally have excellent DICOM-oriented search/navigation tools.